# Wicket manage differents authentication sections

Tags: authentication, wicket

I'm working on a platform which contains several applications (sections). Each application owns her database. To access to one application, the user has to log in. So I use authrole system but the problem is I've only one WicketApplication class which must implement getWebSessionClass and getSignInClass methods. I would like to be able to return the correct class depending on the concerned application.

here is the code of the two methods :

```
@Override
protected Class<? extends AbstractAuthenticatedWebSession> getWebSessionClass() {
return BasicAuthenticationSession.class;
}

@Override
protected Class<? extends WebPage> getSignInPageClass() {
return SignInPage.class;
}
```

Comment: Each specialization of AuthenticatedWebApplication could provide its own override of these methods. It is not very clear what is the problem you face. Please give more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help ! Finally, I've chosen to set up one Authentication page for all applications. And with a system of booleans, I manage the different access to each section.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you mean, but you could assign `Roles` to the user based on their credentials.

These roles can be used to protect for example pages.

For example:

```
@AuthorizeInstantiation( User.ROLE_APP_A_USER )
public class MySubApplicationAPage extends WebPage { ... }
```